# How to handle Shadow-dom elements using selenium Webdriver for Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm testing an application using java-selenium Webdriver where there are some shadow-dom elements. How can I test them for Firefox driver?

I tried the following code

```
WebElement ele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",element);
return ele;
```

This works for Chrome. But for Firefox, I get a "Javascript Exception: Cyclic object error". Could you please help

Comment: Read out this link https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver

Comment: @stacktome Hey. I tried the Firefox method mentioned in the link you gave. I'm getting a "TimeOut exception - waited for 5 seconds but element not visible"

Comment: update question with new code and error.

Answer (score 3):

Not a fix, but as a work around..

Instead of 
"return arguments[0].shadowRoot"
use 
"return arguments[0].shadowRoot.children"
This will return a collection of the root nodes and you can index or use your favorite collection query method to move forward.